# Asp.net validating date file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I make sure that int caseNo3 will be a counter(+1) as long it is not the first day of the month? If it is the first day of the month which is 01,then the counter will reset to 0?

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int caseNo1 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));
        int caseNo2 = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM"));
        int caseNo3 = 0;

        int currentDD=Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd"));

        if (currentDD != 1)
        {
            caseNo3++;

            lbl_display.Text = caseNo1.ToString() + caseNo2.ToString("00") + caseNo3.ToString("000");
        }
```

Above is my logic that Ive came up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int currentDD= DateTime.Now.Day;

        if (currentDD != 1)
        {
            caseNo3++;

            lbl_display.Text = caseNo1.ToString() + caseNo2.ToString("00") + caseNo3.ToString("000");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increment the counter each time you click the button, then `caseNo3` should be a field of your class and not a local variable